# how i can print data table to specific printer by group by in jasper Reports?

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports

i have table is name Mr_items i need when i select any of this items i need to print into by group by in jasper report to column it_print

```
item_sn  |  item_name  | it_print
---------------------------------
1        |  pepsi      | drinks

2        |  sandwiches | foods

3        |  water      | drinks

4        |  burger     | foods
```

i try to print by this code

```
///print invoice cashier
    public void PrintInvoiceSection() throws JRException, IOException {

        try {

            /////////print///////////////////
            HashMap parameters = new HashMap();

            parameters.put("nameilll", cashier_name.getText().trim());
            parameters.put("datevist", sysdate_invc.getText().trim());
            parameters.put("timevist", systime_invc.getText().trim());
            parameters.put("invoice_type", InvoiceType.getText());
            parameters.put("invoiceno", inv_id);
            parameters.put("cus_name", cusName.getText().trim());
            parameters.put("cus_mobile", cusMobile.getText().trim());
            parameters.put("cus_address", cusAddrss.getText());
            parameters.put("inv_remark", customerBehestRemark.getText());
            parameters.put("inv_remark", invoiceRemark.getText());
            InputStream ul = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/printer/Printsection.jasper");
            java.util.Vector collection = new java.util.Vector();
            collection = new Vector(itemslist);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ul, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection));
            JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
            jv.setVisible(false);
            PrintReportToPrinterSection(jasperPrint);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SalesinterfaceController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

and this code also for select the printer

```
private void PrintReportToPrinterSection(JasperPrint jp) throws JRException {
//      getSectionPrint();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        // printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); //setting page size
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

        PrinterName printerName = new PrinterName(cashPrint.getText(), null); //gets printer 

        PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
        printServiceAttributeSet.add(printerName);

        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printServiceAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.getPrintService();
    }
```

i try this syntax

```
SELECT item_sn, item_name, it_print,
       IF($P{consolidate_loc}, concat(itemname, ', ', itemprice, ' ', itemprint ), Mr_items) AS groupField
FROM 
GROUP BY groupField;
```

i cant to include it into jasper report because i don't i know about the field in jasper i'm new bie on it :)

Comment: @Marc Dear mark where you explained give me the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution

////this class for print form into printers

```
public void PrintReportToPrinterSection(JasperPrint jp, String pp) throws PrinterException {
try{

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        // printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); //setting page size
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

        PrinterName printerName = new PrinterName(pp, null); //gets printer 

        PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
        printServiceAttributeSet.add(printerName);

            PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
            PrintService selectedService = null;

            if(services.length != 0 || services != null)
            {
                for(PrintService service : services){
                    String existingPrinter = service.getName().toLowerCase();
            Object selectedPrinter = pp;
                    if(existingPrinter.equals(selectedPrinter))
                    {
                        selectedService = service;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(selectedService != null)
                {
                    printerJob.setPrintService(selectedService);
                    boolean printSucceed = JasperPrintManager.printReport(pp, false);
                }}
        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printServiceAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.exportReport();
} catch (JRException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
    }
```

///print section printer form

///then i call the class into printSection form class 
/// then i do while loop to get for each row by row by group by printer name

```
public void PrintInvoiceSection() throws JRException, SQLException, PrinterException {

        try {
            String sql2 = "select pr_id as printId, pr_printer as printName from invoices_items where tr_inv_no='" + inv_id + "' Group BY pr_id";
            rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql2);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int prind = rs.getInt("printId");
                String prnam = rs.getString("printName");
                JasperDesign jasperdesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\Wael\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\resrr\\resturnopos\\src\\printer\\Printsection.jrxml");

                String sql = "SELECT resturno.mr_printsection.pr_section,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_it_name,\n" +
"       resturno.invoices_items.tr_date,\n" +
"       resturno.invoices_items.tr_inv_issued,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_it_price,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_vat,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_it_qty,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_it_tot,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_inv_no,\n" +
"   resturno.mr_invoicetyp.inv_name1,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.inv_typ_id,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_it_name,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_it_price,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_vat,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_it_tot,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.tr_it_qty,\n" +
"   resturno.mr_invoicetyp.inv_name1,\n" +
"   resturno.mr_invoicetyp.inv_name2,\n" +
"   resturno.mr_printsection.pr_section,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.pr_id,\n" +
"   resturno.invoices_items.pr_printer\n" +
"FROM resturno.invoices_items\n" +
"   INNER JOIN resturno.mr_invoicetyp ON \n" +
"    resturno.mr_invoicetyp.inv_typ_id = resturno.invoices_items.inv_typ_id \n" +
"   INNER JOIN resturno.mr_printsection ON \n" +
"    resturno.mr_printsection.pr_id = resturno.invoices_items.pr_id \n" +
"WHERE  \n"
                    + "  resturno.invoices_items.tr_inv_no = '" + inv_id + "' \n"
                    + "  AND resturno.invoices_items.pr_id = '" + prind + "'"
                    + "  AND resturno.invoices_items.pr_printer = '" + prnam + "'";
                JRDesignQuery jrq = new JRDesignQuery();
                jrq.setText(sql);
                jasperdesign.setQuery(jrq);
                JasperReport jsp = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperdesign);
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jsp, new HashMap(), con);
//              List jpList = new ArrayList();
//              jpList.add(j.loadObjectFromFile("build/reports/Report1.jrprint")); 
                JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
                jv.setVisible(true);
                PrintReportToPrinterSection(jasperPrint, prnam);
            }
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```